# How could I cause metal to rust rapidly?

Tags: redox, metal, applied-chemistry, chemistry-in-fiction

I'm writing a novel set in the mid-nineteenth century. One of my characters needs to cause an iron padlock to rust rapidly, ideally within a matter of hours.

The lock doesn't need to rust away completely - the goal is just to make it noisey and annoying so that it can't be opened in silence.

Is this a realistic goal? If so, what methods could someone use to cause rapid rusting? Bonus points for suggesting period-appropriate materials.

Update: Based on the answer and comments below, it sounds a period appropriate approach would be to mix fine copper filings with saltwater and apply it to the lock.

I've read that bleach is an oxidizing agent which was available in the 19th century. Would adding bleach to this mixture increase the rate of rusting without creating an overly dangerous mixture?

Update: I conducted an experiment in my garage. Iodine worked pretty well.
[Experiment Video](https://youtu.be/t3HrOirO8Ao)

A few months later the iodine had eaten through the lid of the jar I tested it in:

[image: Iodine Ate Through My Jar]

Comment: I've removed the oxidizing agent thing because I'm afraid they would dissolve the rust...

Comment: @user34388 and others - I am not a chemist. What are your thoughts on the risks of trying this experiment? I find the oxidizing agent compelling and it sounds like that might be necessary to reach the goal of rust within hours.

Comment: This experiment is not harmful... as long as you don't use oxidizing agents that are too dangerous such as ([should I be listing them?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_stuff_beans_up_your_nose)) acidified potassium dichromate or acidified potassium permanganate.

Comment: @user34388 At worst I'd be using household bleach, however I'm intrigued by your suggestion with beans, that had not occurred to me...

Comment: What do you mean by "rust"? Having the whole surface thoroughly cover with a layer of rust is not a problem. Run a piece of (unseasoned) iron through the dishwasher and you'll see it. Having the padlock rust through and through like in the fable of the rope made of ash is a different matter, as the rust on the surface will shield the metal from the stuff you through at it from outside.

Comment: @rumtscho - the goal is to make the lock (and associated hinges) on a trapdoor as loud and frustrating as possible so that my protagonist will be able to hear the antagonist open the lock while retaining some deniability - rust can happen naturally, so the antagonist won't immediately assume it's been tampered with.

Comment: Picasso's son has reported that there was a period when his father would tell him to "go piss on the goat"  (http://www.moma.org/collection/works/81670) to encourage the desired patina to develop. Salt water...

Comment: Just a note to Tyler in regards to the nail in your experiment, most modern nails actually have a vinyl coating on them, I believe this is for rust prevention and as a dry lube also.

Comment: The answers and comments should win a prize for obfuscation. Steel /iron rusts when wet, and rusts faster with any salt in the water.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are factors that would speed up rusting:

- Presence of **water**: make sure that the iron is wet.
- Presence of **oxygen**: make sure the iron have access to air (the dissolved oxygen in water also works).
- Presence of **metal** below iron in the metal reactivity series (see the picture below): usually copper is used. Tie copper to iron. Make sure that they are in contact. The larger the surface area of contact the better.
- **Temperature**: make the iron as warm as possible.
- Presence of **salt**: explained [here](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=552). In short, salt increases the conductivity of water which makes the iron rusts faster, since rusting involves electron transfer.
- **Acidic** environment: since rusting involves hydrogen ions ($\ce{H+}$), an acidic environment would increase the concentration of hydrogen ions, making the iron rust faster. **However, this would dissolve the rust.**
- Presence of **hydrogen peroxide**: hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) is an oxidizing agent which would not dissolve the rust:
  $$\ce{3H2O2 + 2Fe -> 3H2O + Fe2O3}$$

Metal reactivity series:

[image]
<sub>(source: [bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/staticarchive/18dee1116c8d50fe49f99a06f3cbd715531b583e.gif))</sub>

Equation of rusting:

- $\ce{Fe -> Fe^3+ + 3e-}$
- $\ce{O2 + 4H+ + 4e- -> 2H2O}$
- $\ce{2Fe^3+ + 3H2O -> Fe2O3 + 6H+}$

More equations can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust#Associated_reactions).

Overall equation:

$$\ce{4Fe + 3O2 ->[H+,H2O] 2Fe2O3}$$

Comment: Maybe an acidic environment would favour rusting. If you see the electrochemical aspect of rusting, the H+ ions are on the left hand side of the cell equation for rusting

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal But wouldn't acid dissolve the rust?

Comment: @busukxuan I think the question poster just needs the padlock to go away, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @busukxuan the question only asks methods to speed up the process of rusting. SO,the OP is interested in speeding up the oxidation of iron and for that increasing [H+] would serve the purpose.I do not know if acid would dissolve it or not but  that is asked. However, if you know what shall be the reaction of Fe2O3.xH2O with H+(i.e. dissolution of Fe3+ in acid), do mention in the comment. I would like to know that.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal Not long ago I used HCl to remove rust. Basically it's just the hydroxide reacting with acid to form water, while there acid's conjugated base forms a salt with the iron.

Comment: @user34388 the objective is to build up rust to make the lock more difficult to open, so washing away the rust would likely defeat the purpose.

Comment: @busukxuan thanks for the explanation.  I was confusing myself with this statement of my chemistry book which discusses rusting only till the generation of Fe2+. It stated that electrons released at the anodic spot move through the metal to another spot to reduce oxygen in presence of H+(from acidic oxides in air). There was also a statement that Fe2+ would further be oxidised to Fe3+ and release some H+ ions (which I did not pay attention to.)

Comment: @user34388 your post is now better. I've transformed my vote to and upvote. HOWEVER, note that the actual reactions for rusting are quite complex and proceed in many steps.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal I cannot come up with the equation of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ being oxidized to become $\ce{Fe^3+}$ while giving off $\ce{H+}$...

Comment: Nitpick: It's not *just* salt: $\ce{NaCl}$ is an especially effective salt for inducing corrosion/rust due to the chloride ion. Halides generally (fluoride being the odd duck out, usually) are awesome at inducing corrosion.

Comment: When I was 10 or 12 or whatever chemistry-set age is, I remember following some instructions to make a solution that would cause nails to rust within a few minutes. I've no idea whether this was actual rust from the nail or was perhaps simply something deposited on its surface. Any idea what this solution was? (perhaps bleach or ammonia) ¶ This was back in the 1960s, so the range of commonly available chemicals was much greater than it is today (e.g. I remember going to the local pharmacy and buying liquid mercury, potassium permanganate (and glycerine), potassium nitrate (and sulphur), etc.).

Answer (score 9):

Here's a less-known effect:  Iron or steel exposed to iodine vapors will rust within hours.

Also, in a draft-free room, iodine crystals placed well above an iron object will evaporate, creating a descending vapor-plume which rusts everything directly below.   Or just use overkill: affix a sack of black iodine powder over the steel to be rusted.   (Also, iodine has a distinct odor, so an S. Holmes type might sniff the rust and learn much, while normal humans would never think to try.)

Historical:  currently iodine crystals are only sold for treating lifestock, but 170 years ago it was a common photographic chemical (critical in Daguerrotype process,) and also a common antiseptic.  Perhaps your local Victorian druggist would have kilos of raw solid iodine to supply the daguerrotype craze, if not just for mixing up some iodine tincture for treating small cuts.

Comment: I set up an experiment to test this. I put approximately 15g of iodine crystals on a plastic mesh about 2" above a steel nail. After about 18 hours I'm seeing a little rust starting to form. It's about 55 defrees Fahrenheit, so the sublimation of the iodine may be slower than yoir response expected.

Comment: When I saw this happen, it was above 70F and quite humid as well.   It might be humidity that does it, rather than just heat.   Also, even a slight oil-film (such as with store-bought nails) might interfere  ...which probably removes this idea from the running.   Your door hinge would already have to be grease-free and probably squeaky.

Comment: In the book the temperature will be comparable to my test. I expect I'll have the characters use a degreasing solvent (lye?) before applying iodine.

Comment: @Tyler  IDEA!   If you have iodine crystals, you can use ammonia to make contact explosive paste.  Ammonium iodide.  Smeared on a hinge or in a keyhole, after drying, it goes POW when disturbed even slightly.   Just use a small stick to thoroughly grind up about a cc of black iodine crystals immersed in a saucer of ammonia cleaner.  Keep adding more ammonia until the violet turns blue-gray.  Let it settle out.  The paste can be made on the spot as needed.  It's dangerous to store it wet in a sealed container, but can be done briefly (just not for ~days.)  Don't make more than 1cc at a time!

Comment: @Tyler  Loud crackling floor:  make an entire cc of the black stuff, fling it at the ground hard, so it spatters.  Wait to dry.  Now anyone walking on the floor makes all kinds of crackling noises, even some quite loud pops.   Sometimes it lasts for weeks!  .  .  Also the ammonium iodide makes a small purple cloud of iodine, and if exploding from a keyhole, will stain the hand.    Which perp was messing with a prepared lock?  Check for purple hand!

Comment: that's awesome! I may have to try it. I'll comment when i do.

Comment: @Tyler But is it Victorian?   Hell yeah.  Discovery announced in 1813.  Studied by Humphy Davy etc.  See:  https://books.google.com/books?id=LmQ2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA130

Comment: excellent. Thanks for the help, I'll set aside a free copy for you when it's done!

Comment: I did some more research on this. What you're describing is ammoniated nitrogentriiodide. When it explodes, ammonia triodide is left over. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_iodide

Comment: Yep, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_triiodide.   There are LOTS of chemistry demo videos on youtube for this.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the results of my garage experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The squeaky performance of the padlock need not come completely from within. If the idea of copper filings is acceptable (they would certainly seem out of place), perhaps a little plaster of Paris could be made into a paste and shoved into the keyhole. After it sets, the operation of the lock would be stiff, perhaps noisy. The plaster could be retarded or not, so as to set hours later or within minutes.

For chemical complexity, you could add iron (not copper!) filings - let the added metal do the rusting. It could look like the padlock was just wearing out. Plaster need not stay white; if the iron filings don't color it enough, there's always carbon black. And NaCl if you want some rusting; and some oxalic acid, or cream of tartar for acidity - or NaHSO<sub>4</sub>.

This could work even if the padlock is brass, although brass filings would look more innocent. But the plaster should be colored so as to look like dirt.

Perhaps even a little Portland cement, as a paste, maybe a little sand, maybe some iron filings for extra rusting. This would be more adhesive, but would take longer to set, unless you add a little CaCl<sub>2</sub> for acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

[Science At Play: Instant Rust | Connecticut Science Center](https://ctsciencecenter.org/blog/science-at-play-instant-rust/) describes a children's experiment (including a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xba76XUMbw&ab_channel=ConnecticutScienceCenter)
) for causing iron to rust almost instantly:

In a non-metallic container, add:

- eight parts hydrogen peroxide (standard 3% concentration).
- one part vinegar (standard 5% acetic acid).

While stirring, slowly add until no more will dissolve:

- table salt.

Then:

- Place an uncoated non-galvanized nail in the liquid.
- Watch it develop rust.
- Carefully remove and allow to air dry before touching the rust.

> In our experiment, mixing hydrogen peroxide (H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>) and distilled vinegar together creates a small amount of something called peracetic acid.
> Acid is corrosive and can cause things like metal to break down.
> Hydrogen peroxide is made of hydrogen and oxygen, but it’s the oxygen that’s key to creating rust on metal.
>
> The molecules of iron on the surface of the nail exchange atoms with the oxygen in the solution and produce a new substance.
> You guessed it–rust! (or iron oxide as scientists would call it!)
>
> This whole process is helped along by the salt we added to the solution.
> Its job in this whole process is to act as an electrolyte which lowers the electrical resistance in the solution, helping the oxygen and the nail to trade atoms more easily.

This is intended to be kid-safe (with appropriate precautions), but for your situation, a more strongly concentrated solution might be considered.