# I suspended iodine over steel nails. What are these droplets that formed?

Tags: home-experiment, oxidation-state, sublimation

I suspended about 15g of iodine crystals over a couple of nails to see how quickly they would begin to rust.

After a week, these droplets had formed. When prodded they broke apart like water drops.

What are these? My guess is that the iodine sublimated and then combined with water vapor.

[The original question that prompted this experiment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/how-could-i-cause-metal-to-rust-rapidly).

[image: Mystery droplets]

The setup (~one week prior)

[image: Experiment Setup]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iodine vapors combine with iron to form iron(II) iodide:$$\ce{I2 + Fe->FeI2}$$ In an anhydrous form the compound is dark red-purple. But iron(II) iodide is hygroscopic and deliquescent which means that it dissolves in moisture it absorbs from the air, and forms those droplets. This complicates a bit the chemistry of the droplets - the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ion exists most likely in a form of various aquo-, hydroxo- and iodo- complexes. Also, when an iodide anion and elementary iodine are present together they form triiodide anions:$$\ce{I- + I2->I3-}$$ Therefore, the droplets are a solution of a rather complicated mixture of iron and iodine compounds.